# facebooker plugin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

i have a question that i want to get notifications from my facebook application?
means that users on some other site can get notification related to my facebook application. 
there is send notifications option in facebooker plugin but no way i see get notification option. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

there is no receive notification method. the sent notifications will appear on the facebook page of the user you have sent the notification.